# Dynamic object creation

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ programming and I have a basic issue,  I want to create N  objects, N is   is actually a user input.

I am specific about having object names, say *beam1*, beam2,...,beamX.

2 quick things

1. Is it possible in C++ to create dynamic object as this?
2. if it is how do we do tht? I am pasting code for your refrence..

   ```
       #include "iostream"
       # include <conio.h>
       using namespace std;

       // Static member variable is defined outside the class..
       class beam {
       public:
       int length;
       };

       int main () 
       {
          int i=0, no_of_spans, j;
          cout<< "Design Of a Continous Beam \n1) No Of Spans : ";
          cin >> no_of_spans;
          for (i =0; i < no_of_spans; i++) {
            j = i;
            beam;
            cout << "Length of Beam" << j+1 << " is : ";
            cin >> beami.length;
          }

          cout << "\nPress any key to continue..\n";
          getch ();
       }
   ```

This is obviously a code with errors, its put up as an example to get the idea.

Comment: THis is why the language has arrays, and the library has std::vector.

Comment: Why is the dynamic creation of the variable name important?

Comment: @hmjd coz i want it that way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been stated by others (Luchian, John, Component and Ed) you can use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and it will dynamically grow as necessary to store the number of `beam` objects required.

If you wish to refer to these objects later by name you could store them in a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), with the key of the map being the object name (e.g. beam1, beam2, beam3, ..., beamX):

```
std::map<std::string, beam> beams;
for (int i = 0; i < no_of_spans; i++)
{
    j = i;
    beam beam;
    std::string beam_name("beam" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i + 1));
    cout << "Length of " << beam_name << " is : ";
    cin >> beam.length;
    beams.insert(std::make_pair(beam_name, beam));
}
```

--

`boost::lexical_cast<>` is a mechanism for converting (in this case) an `int` to a `std::string`. There other ways to achieve this (using `std::ostringstream` for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::vector` to store the objects.

You use `push_back` to add elements to the `vector`.

Something along the lines of:

```
std::vector<beams> beamCollection;
for (i =0; i < no_of_spans; i++) {
    j = i;
    beam beami;
    cout << "Length of Beam" << j+1 << " is : ";
    cin >> beami.length;
    beamCollection.push_back(beami);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it's possible.  There are several ways.

One way, the way I'd prefer if possible/practical, is to use `std::vector` and `push_back`, `transform` or `generate_n` how ever many objects you needed.

Another way is to use `new` to allocate an array of the object you want.  This is less preferred to using a `vector` however, because by using `new` you take on the responsibility of managing the memory -- there needs to be a `delete` that corresponds to every `new`.  This can be mitigated by using a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr`, but it's often best to just avoid the cactus altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Your best bet is to use an  appropriate STL collection and dynamically grow it at runtime by adding / removing objects.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no - the compiler needs to know the names of variables at compile time.

You need to use an array (or vector).

Comment: I don't think the user is constrained to using compile-time arrays.

Comment: @JohnDibling - The OP asked for variables to be called beam1, beam2 etc. i.e. create the variable names on the fly. This is not possible in C or C++. The compiler needs to know the names of the variables at compile time.